# Delegate methods for UITableView inside UIPageViewController not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a series of VC's containing a tableview inside a pageviewcontroller, when it presents the first view all is fine and delegates are called.

However after swiping the view goes blank, i can still see the background colour of the VC, the debugger shows the table is added to the view, but theres no contents. This seems to be caused due to delegate methods not being called, however it is the same controller template as the working initial view is created with. What could be the cause of this?

Code for the page controller setup, the child views are set up as typical tableviews with the usual delegate methods:

```
extension PollContainerViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> PollQuestionAndResultViewController? {
    if self.selectedPoll.questions.count == 0 || index >= self.selectedPoll.questions.count {
        return nil
    }
    let PollQuestionResultViewController = PollQuestionAndResultViewController(pollQuestionView: PollQuestionAndResultView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds), selectedPoll: self.selectedPoll, pageID: self.pageID, pageIndex: index)
    return PollQuestionResultViewController
}


func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard var index = (viewController as! PollQuestionAndResultViewController).pageIndex else {return nil}
    pageControl.currentPage = index
    if (index <= 0) {
        return nil
    }
    index -= 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard var index = (viewController as! PollQuestionAndResultViewController).pageIndex else {return nil}
    pageControl.currentPage = index
    index += 1
    if (index >= self.selectedPoll.questions.count) {
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)
}
```

VDL setup:

```
func configurePollQuestions() {
    pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    pageViewController.dataSource = self
    if let startPollQuestionViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) {
        self.viewControllers.append(startPollQuestionViewController)
    }
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(self.viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false) { (finished) -> Void in }
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40)
    pageControl.numberOfPages = selectedPoll.questions.count
    pageControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    pageViewController.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

debugger image:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated question... is that XCode? or something like IBM BlueMix... :/

Comment: its reveal, knew someone would ask that rather than answer the question! ha

Comment: now back to your question :D, Your code shows nothing related to the TableView... one question, is First view controller generated the same way all other VCs are? maybe you sat delegate and dataSource inside storyboard for that one...

Comment: all VCs are created from the same class instance yes, i didnt show the code as its just a standard tableview class, it works for the first child view, but when i scroll no delegates are called leading to the screenshot where the table is added but has no cells, the very first time it loads, it looks fine. I dont use storyboards i set the delegate and datasource in the viewdidload of the class

Comment: I assume you have something like `pollQuestionView.tableView.delegate = self` inside `PollQuestionAndResultViewController` right?

Comment: yepi run that in the VDL

Comment: I once faced this problem with collectionView. and after clean build, my problem was solved. But to further research into it, print tableView.delegate and dataSource everytime you go inside a viewController... call tableView.reloadData in multiple places and if it worked, reverse engineer to see where's the problem... hope it helps..